# In hibernate why does the saving the same entity object twice won't work

Tags: hibernate

In hibernate why if I am saving the same object twice it is not saving like in the below code I am saving employee object twice but it is not saving.It is saving only once with id 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Session session = HibUtility.getSessionFactory().openSession()){
            System.out.println("session===:: session"+session);
            Employee employee=getEmployee();
            System.out.println("employee==::"+employee);
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(employee);
            session.save(employee);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? (Also never leave that empty catch block. At the minimum log the exception or you won't have any clue what is going in when stuff "doesn't work".)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are saving the same `Employee` instance .That 's why there is only one employee record is created. What you need to do it is to create two separate `Employee` instances :

```
Employee employee1 = getEmployee();
session.save(employee1);

Employee employee2 = getEmployee();
session.save(employee2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of an ORM such as hibernate is to abstract the database away from your code and simply allow you to think of it as a generic object container. You create your entity once and put it into the container. Once you have put it into the container the first time hibernate tracks it and any time it gets taken our before being put back into the container hibernate knows it's the object you took out and does an update rather than an insert.

In your example above, hibernate did an insert on  the first call to save and an update on the second... well that's an oversimplification, because on the second call, hibernate knew nothing had changed and effectively did nothing, but that's none of your concern... which is the beauty of the ORM abstraction.